# Access wildcard search

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am trying to get the user enter ">" / "<" when doing a search. As it stands now user can enter just a number. If user enters > or < it'll give a message indicating that this is too complicate to evaluate. I don't want to use 2 parameters to enter this search criteria.

```
SELECT MissingTF469.[Case ID+], 
       MissingTF469.AuthManager, 
       MissingTF469.[Client Login+], 
       MissingTF469.[Client Name+], 
       MissingTF469.[Case Information], 
       MissingTF469.EmailDate, 
       MissingTF469.ECount 
FROM   MissingTF469 
WHERE  ( 
( ( MissingTF469.ECount ) = [Forms] ! [FormEmailCount] ! [TxtEmailCount] )
) 
ORDER  BY MissingTF469.EmailDate;
```

Is there anyway to get this done?

Comment: Where in the query would the user's input actually go, and what would the ideal query look like?

Comment: It will be on a form. That form's will open the query from clicking on a command button on it. So just before the click the command button they will have to enter the number in the form.( MissingTF469.ECount ) = [Forms] ! [FormEmailCount] ! [TxtEmailCount] ). This will be carry forward into the query. But at the moment user is unable to enter any wildcards in it. I want them to be able to enter > or < query.